# Group JMenuItems in Java

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am creating an application in Java in which I would like the Menu Items to be grouped like we see in many applications.

Here is an example:
[image: From Google Chrome on Mac]
Notice how a gray bar is visually separating the options. 
How is this done in Java (Swing) — can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [JMenu API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenu.html) describes an `addSeparator()` method that should do just what you want.

i.e.,

```
JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
editMenu.add(new JMenuItem("Foo"));
editMenu.add(new JMenuItem("Bar"));
editMenu.addSeparator();
editMenu.add(new JMenuItem("Baz"));
editMenu.add(new JMenuItem("Bif"));
```

Comment: Perfect – thanks! Works like a charm. Will go mark your answer as the solution when some more time has passed.